# Got Segmentation fault on accessing char array in function strcpy()

Tags: c++

## Question

I am always getting segmentation fault when I use the following code. Is there something wrong or we cannot write in this particular array.

## CODE

```
char *Strcpy(char *str1,const char *str2){
    for(int i = 0; *str1 ; i++){
        *(str1+i) = *(str2+i);
        if(*(str2+i)=='\0'){
            *(str1+i) = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    return str1;
} 
int main(){
    char* s1=(char*)"Hello World";
    char* s2=(char*)"It's String";
    char* t = Strcpy(s1,s2);
    cout<<t<<endl;
}
```

## ERROR

**Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555f939 in Strcpy(char*, char const*)**

Comment: `"Hello World"` is a string literal, and those are immutable. Your compiler would've told you this, but because of the `(char *)` cast it assumed you know what you're doing.

Comment: Is there any possible way to write in this array.

Comment: `str1+i` when `*str1` is pointing at the end of the string. And I don't think it is a good idea to write to literal memory space.

Comment: @TechJuice02 Create an actual array: `char s1[] = "Hello World";`.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to dynamically allocate strings inside a `char*`, then use [`strdup()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup)...

Comment: "Is there something wrong" - Yes. You are trying to modify a `const`ant character literal. That's [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: `(char*)` is a [C-Style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). They're basically the word of God to the compiler. Using one tells the compiler to turn off all of its brains, checking, and other safety measures and do exactly what you say. They are old deep magic and you need to know exactly what you are doing in order to safely use a cast like this. Prefer to use the more restricted casts available in C++. [Start with `static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) and only use a more permissive cast when forced to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals like `"Hello World"` have type `char const[]` and are stored in read-only memory, trying to change them crashes your application. Casting away `const` like you do won't fix that.

One fix would be to allocate the destination string on the stack:

```
char s1[] = "Hello World";
```

---

You may like to copy strings in a simpler canonical fashion:

```
char *Strcpy(char *dst, const char *src) {
    char* r = dst;
    while(*dst++ = *src++); // <--- canonical string copy
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Yup! Thats the one possible way.
But can we do this with forced casting like in my case

Comment: @TechJuice02 No.

Comment: @TechJuice02, Modifying the contents of a `const char[]` is UB

Comment: Thanks! I got it.

Comment: "trying to change them crashes your application" Not necessarily. But trying to change them *is* undefined behaviour, so *anything* could happen (the *entire* program is invalid due to the UB).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in the following lines should not be done:

```
char* s1=(char*)"Hello World";
char* s2=(char*)"It's String";
```

A string literal such as "Hello World" is stored in read-only memory and is therefore not allowed to be modified. That is why string literals have the type modifier `const` in C++ (this does not apply to the language C, even if they are read-only there too). For this reason, you should never point to them using a non-const pointer of type `char *`.

If you want to store the string in writeable memory, you must allocate a char array and initialize it, like this:

```
char s1[] = "Hello World";
char s2[] = "It's String";
```

However, when doing this, it will only allocate enough memory for storing the string, including its null terminator. If you want to be able to increase the size of the string, then you must allocate more memory. Alternatively, you can simply use `std::string`, which takes care of memory allocation for you and allocates extra memory as needed.

Comment: String literals are not `const char *`, they are `const char[]`